# How would you check if the user has been active and push it to Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have no idea how to even go about doing this feature but I'm trying to check if the user has been active in the last four months and if they haven't delete their account. My app uses Parse.com and objective-c.

I would really appreciate any help.

Edit: @YuviGr helped me with the logic of the code but if you'd like to take a look at the finished code you can visit it by going to:

Comment: why not use the updatedAt value in each object?

Comment: What is that @YuviGr ? And how would I do something like that ?

Comment: I have posted a response for you, let me know it that helped you or not so i could adjust my answer

Comment: Hi @YuviGr, thanks for your help. I'm trying it right now!

Answer (score 1):

Every object you insert into the Parse.com DataBase has 4 default values.

- `objectId`
- `createdAt`
- `updatedAt`
- `ACL`

You can use the updatedAt value to figure out when was the last time the user entered the app.
Just remember to save the user every time he logs into the app so the updatedAt value can be updated.

As for the detection and deletion. You can do the test once a user tries to log in your app, if the last time he logged was more then X months then delete/invalidate the user account.

Comment: Hi @YuviGr, thanks for the help. I've implemented this into my app but I have yet to see if it works. I can't seem to be able to change the updatedAt value on Parse.com. Is there any way I can test this? Thanks for your help. Arman.

Comment: Hi @YuviGr. Seeing your active on Parse and Objective-C discussions I was wondering if you could help me with my new post over [here]  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798343/login-with-username-or-email-with-parse-com-and-obj-c). Thanks again! ~armanb21

Comment: All the default values i have told you about in my answer will update automatically.. all you have to do is save an object and the updatedAt value will get the current time